# Ruby get return from system command (sox)

Tags: ruby

I am trying to assign the stats from a `sox` command to a ruby variable. When using `system` I get 'true/false' depending on success of command. So I've tried:

```
%x{ sox file -n stats }
```

This shows stats in my console, but actually returns an empty string, like so:

```
Stat: 123
Another stat: 234
""
```

I want to obtain the string that contains the stats. Is this possible?

Comment: so in the end you want `123456` in your ruby var?

Comment: `%x{ ... }` will capture the stdout of the subshell and return it as a string.  If you're seeing output on the console but not getting it in the return, most likely the program is writing to stderr instead of stdout.  Try: `%x{ sox file -n stats 2>&1 }` to get both stdout and stderr directed to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use back ticks:

```
result = `sox file -n stats`
```

Make sure that sox doesn't output to STDERR. In such case redirect.

```
result = `sox file -n stats 2>&1`
```

**Edit**
Back ticks and `%x{}` are the same. Sorry. I mixed it up with `system`. Redirect is most probably what you need.

Comment: It's the same. From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60): *The built-in syntax `%x{...}` uses this method.*

Comment: @Stefan Right. I thought it went down to `system`.